# Same code one gives error other one doesn't in iOS

Tags: ios, error-handling

For my own project, I have used `AGImagePickerController`.

I copied all the necessary files into my project. Weird thing is I received some errors.

I have commented them out and decided to fix them later on. Errors make no sense since in the demo project, there are no errors like that. for instance, the first thing I wanted to fix was the cancel button.

When it's clicked, `AGImagePickerCOntroller` should be dismissed..    `[((AGImagePickerController *)self.navigationController) performSelector:@selector(didCancelPickingAssets)];`

The error is `'undeclared selector didCancelPickingAssets`'.

How come it gives no errors in the example project whereas I am getting some errors?

Thanks

Comment: Let's start simple. Do you have something along the lines of -(void)didCancelPickingAssets; in you .h file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check the code of [AGImagePickerController](https://github.com/arturgrigor/AGImagePickerController) you'll see that `-(void)didCancelPickingAssets;` is declared in `@interface` in .m file so it is ment to be used as a *private* method.

To avoid the error you're getting move the declaration into the `@interface` part in the .h file - this could lead to other problems though.